# In PyCharm the Jupyter Server tool window to preview server's configuration details gives nothing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I use PyCharm Professional and I am trying to launch Jupyter Notebook inside PyCharm IDE.
I followed the official instructions [Manage Jupyter notebook servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-jupyter-notebook.html).

I installed Jupyter and configured python 3.8 interpreter using virtual environment. I do not use conda.

When I run the first cell "Starting Jupyter Server" message is shown on the Jupyter top bar. I now that I have to insert Jupyter password or activation token for the server.

When I run command inside PyCharm terminal it gives me only the address:

```
jupyter notebook list
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/
```

[image]
As officials say here must be shown authentication token for the server, but it is missing.

So, where I can find this token to enter the Jupyter Server and see other server's configuration details?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer by myself.

I have Jupyter configuration already in the folder `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` where the password and other parameters are set. So, to enter the server all I had to do is to enter the password which I set on my own in the above configuration file in the past.